# parsing non GNU-standard options using optparse in python

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, optparse

For some reason, I have non standard command line options for my program. My program takes in a long option also with a single '-'. For example, a valid command line option would be '-f' / '-foo'. Both short and long options need to have an argument separated by space or an '='.

I am trying to parse this using the optparse, but I understand that optparse does not support non GNU-standard options. Is there a way to tweak optparse to do this?

Comment: Note: Using *optparse* is discouraged since python version 2.7. The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the *argparse* module. See [PEP 0389][1] for more info.


  [1]: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/

Comment: @shakaran: a little tip, you use `[inline link format](http://example.com)` (which appears as [inline link format](http://example.com)) in comments to make links.

Comment: Thanks! I will take that in next comment link. Unfortunately I cannot edit my last comment as far I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a mildly hackish way to do what you need.

Subclass `Option` and `OptionParser` and patch some of the methods:

```
from optparse import Option, OptionError, OptionParser

class MyOption(Option):
    def _set_opt_strings(self, opts):
        for opt in opts:
            if len(opt) < 2:
                raise OptionError(
                    "invalid option string %r: "
                    "must be at least two characters long" % opt, self)
            elif len(opt) == 2:
                self._short_opts.append(opt)
            else:
                self._long_opts.append(opt)

class MyOptionParser(OptionParser):
    def _process_args(self, largs, rargs, values):
        while rargs:
            arg = rargs[0]
            if arg == "--":
                del rargs[0]
                return
            elif arg[0:2] == "--":
                self._process_long_opt(rargs, values)
            elif arg[:1] == "-" and len(arg) > 1:
                if len(arg) > 2:
                    self._process_long_opt(rargs, values)
                else:
                    self._process_short_opts(rargs, values)
            elif self.allow_interspersed_args:
                largs.append(arg)
                del rargs[0]
            else:
                return
```

Now you can do

```
parser = MyOptionParser()
parser.add_option(MyOption("-f", "-file", dest="filename",
                 help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE"))
parser.add_option(MyOption("-q", "-quiet",
                 action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                 help="don't print status messages to stdout"))
```

With this, `parser` will accept `-file` as an option (and will not accept e.g. `-fq`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually helps me. However, when printing the help or if an invalid option is mentioned, it prints the -- option. To be clear. in your above code, if I gave the option as -fle in the command line, the error message would be: "no such option --fle". Where can I change this behavior, so that it prints it as " no such option: -fle"?

Comment: To do that, you'd need to patch `Option`. I've added the necessary patch to my answer.

Comment: I understand that this helps in setting the long option with a single - in the 'Option', so when it prints the help message it would print the option with single -. But the error message that displays for an invalid option is showing a double dash. For Ex: Consider the options you have mentioned above. In the command line if I give an option "-invalid" (an option that does not exist), it prints an error message "no such option --invalid" (this has double dash, but I gave a single dash in the command line). I don't understand how it is changing the cmd line argument to a double dash.

Comment: @user2242512: I updated the patch for `OptionParser` along with `Option`. Be sure you have the new code (I removed a line which converted `-` to `--` as it was no longer necessary with the patched `Option`).

Comment: I kinda figured it out before I saw your reply, but 'Thanks a lot'. This fixes the problem I originally had.

Comment: I have a followup question on this, and I created a new "question" for that. Is it possible for you to take a look and comment on it?:  [overriding OptionParser's add_option function in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821463/overriding-optionparsers-add-option-function-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

From the [optparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#terminology)

> **option:**
>   an argument used to supply extra information to guide or customize the execution of a program. There are many different syntaxes for options; the traditional Unix syntax is a hyphen (“-”) followed by a single letter, e.g. `-x` or `-F`. Also, traditional Unix syntax allows multiple options to be merged into a single argument, e.g. `-x -F` is equivalent to `-xF`. The GNU project introduced `--` followed by a series of hyphen-separated words, e.g. `--file` or `--dry-run`. *These are the only two option syntaxes provided by optparse*.

(emphasis added)

So no, you cannot specify other ways of handling arguments with `optparse`. You can, however, parse the arguments yourself by using `argv` from the [sys module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

This is going to be more work, but it might look something like:

```
from sys import argv
for arg in argv:
    if arg.startswith("-") or arg.startswith("--"):
        # Parse the argument
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already thought of this, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this using optparse. Right now, I am using parser.add_option to add a normal long option. I am then modifying the argv to append a - before the long options so that the optparse.OptionParser can parse it. For Ex: 
parser.add_option("--foo",dest="foo"). if the command line option is -foo, i would parse it and make it '--foo' and send it as an argument to the parser function. But the problem here is that in help it would print the option as --foo, but I want it as -foo. Can I change the help text?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to tweak `optparse` (though I don't know for certain), but [`getopt`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) is your alternative that will handle C style command-line options.