# overriding OptionParser's add_option function in python

Tags: python, optparse

I have written a subclass for `Option` and `OptionParser` in optparse. I am overriding the `add_option` function in OptionParser to make it parse a new keyword. Following is my code.

```
from optparse import Option, OptionError, OptionParser

class MyOptionParser(OptionParser):
    def add_option(self,*args,**kwargs):
    ##add the new keyword "deft". If deft="some value", kwargs[default] = deft
    ##else process args to get deft
        if kwargs.has_key["deft"]:
            newDef = kwargs["deft"]
            del kwargs["deft"]
        else:
            newDef = process_args_for_deft(args)
        if newDef!= None
            kwargs["default"] = newDef
        modOpt = OptionParser.add_option(self,*args,**kwargs)

class MyOption(Option):
    def _set_opt_strings(self, largs, rargs, values):
        #overridden method over here
```

Now if I do this, it works fine.

```
parser = MyOptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                 help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE", deft ="xyz")
```

But if I do this (which I want to) it gives me an error: MyOption instance has no attribute '**getitem**' if def is not specified and if `def` is specified it gives me an error saying no type like `def`.

```
parser = MyOptionParser()
parser.add_option(MyOption("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                 help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE", def ="xyz"))
```

I think the problem is that I am passing an object when I use MyOption (opts,args) and hence it is not able to access the args/kwargs. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Please post the tracebacks, `process_args_for_def` and `MyOption._set_opt_strings` code. Also `def` is a reserved word and can't be used as an explicit argument name.

Comment: Could you post the full traceback? Also, naming a variable `def` should be impossible, since it's a keyword: how is this even running at all?

Comment: I have added the `process_args_for_def`, `MyOption._set_opt_strings` and the traceback. I have a huge code base, and I am only trying to give the part of code relevent here. Also I changed the kewword name and typed it as def instead of deft. Changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_option` basically directly calls the constructor for `option_class` (which is a default argument to the `OptionParser` constructor that defaults to `optparse.Option`).

So, you should probably just override `MyOption.__init__` instead (without overriding `OptionParser.add_option`):

```
class MyOption(Option):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'deft' in kwargs:
            newDef = kwargs.pop('deft')
        else:
            newDef = process_args_for_deft(args)
        if newDef is not None:
            kwargs["default"] = newDef

        Option.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to be able to support syntax like

```
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
             help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE", deft ="xyz")
```

then just make sure to set `option_class` when making your `OptionParser`:

```
parser = MyOptionParser(option_class=MyOption)
```